# Apache POI Can't read content types part

Tags: apache-poi, java-stored-procedures

In Java I have developed a simple program to read DOCX documents. Then I tryed to deploy jar libraries on Oracle database 11g (Java 1.6 version) with loadjava tool. All classes on datbase side are "Valid".

Whe I run the Java stored procedure on database I get exception:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Can't read content types part !
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:120)
at Docx.loadFromBlob(Docx:38)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Can't read content types part !
    at
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.<init>(ContentTypeManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.<init>(ZipContentTypeManager.java:56)
    at
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:167)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:662)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:269)
    at
org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
```

Docx file is fine because I can open it with Java on my client. Also the Java version on my database is the same as on client side (NetBeans)

regards
Peter

Comment: Looks like the file is somehow different when it is received on the Database side, either it is not actually a docx at that point or was corrupted underway? I would either store the bytes somewhere for closer analysis or do a hex-dump of the first few bytes so you can compare with what you have locally.

Comment: The file is not different because I tryed different tests. First one was to call DOCX document from table stored in BLOB field and it works (on client side), second test was opening docx file directly as FileInputStream... The same approach on database as java stored procedure does not work. It give me the error: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Can't read content types part !

Comment: That's why I think that the actual bytes that you receive inside the database are different and thus I suggested to write them out to a file or dump them out somehow to actually see what the difference is here!

Comment: The document is well formed because I tryed on the client side to fetch the "file" from blob field (table) and it work (so the "file" is not corrupted).

Comment: but it seems to be different when it arrives in the POI class when run inside the database so to rule out that there is something tinkering with it in-between I would analyze at that point, if you don't, there is not much more I can suggest...